# Exponents in C++ by using loops

Tags: c++, loops, math, exponent

I need some help. I want to compute a<sup>x</sup> given real value a and positive value integer x.

My program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a, x;

cout << "Input a: ";
cin  >> a;
cout << "Input x: ";
cin  >> x;

for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)
    a= a*a;
    cout << "The answer is: " << a;
}
```

Comment: `I want to produce the output of this program`, What stops you from using a compiler for that?

Comment: Hint: your loop is iterating over the wrong range

Comment: Do you need to use a for loop? Consider using std::pow or math.h

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)
    a= a*a;
    cout << "The answer is: " << a;
}
```

Every time you go through this loop, you multiply a by itself.  Let's suppose the user enters number a<sub>0</sub>.  Then:

- After 0 iterations, a has value a<sub>0</sub>.
- After 1 iteration, a has value a<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>
- After 2 iterations, a has value a<sub>0</sub><sup>4</sup>
- After 3 iterations, a has value a<sub>0</sub><sup>8</sup>
- ...

For example, if a = 2 and x = 4, the values will be 2, 4, 16, and 256, which are way bigger than you want them to be.

To fix this, try changing your loop so that you have a secondary variable, initially set to 1, that you keep multiplying by a.  That way, you don't change what value you're multiplying by on each iteration.

Next, note that your loop is running too many times.  Since you loop up to and including x, your loop runs x + 1 times, so if you want to compute a<sup>x</sup> you will get the wrong value.  Try changing this to loop exactly x times.

Finally, your print statement runs on each iteration, so you'll see all the intermediary values.  Change the code so that the print statement is outside the loop.

After doing all that, do look up the `pow` function.  If this is for an assignment you might not be able to use this function, but it's the easiest way to solve this problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If implemented correctly squaring the value is actually more efficient. Whenever the exponent is divisible by two, one can square the value, e.g. a^6 = (a^2)^3 = (a^2) * (a^2)^2. I'm not sure if that was the intent in the question.

Comment: @dornhege- Definitely. I figured this wasn't the time to introduce exponentiation by squaring, though. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of errors:

```
for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)
```

this will loop for `x+1` times, not what you intended.

```
a= a*a;
```

every time you do this, `a` is the value that is already multiplied, so you need another variable to store the result.

```
int result = 1;
for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    result *= a;  
}
cout << "The answer is: " << result;
```

One last note, to calculate `a^x`, `int` may be too small for many practical cases, consider a bigger type like `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int result = 1;
        for (int i=1; i<=x; i++)
        {
          result= result*a;
        }

            cout << "The answer is: " << result;
        }
```

Hope This will work for you

Comment: You probably want to output `result` at the end, not a...

Answer (score -1):

A more "fun" method would be to use a template:

```
template<unsigned int E>
unsigned int power(unsigned int i)
{
    return i * power<E - 1>(i); // template "loop"
}

template<>
unsigned int power<0>(unsigned int i) // break the "loop"
{
    return 1;
}
```

To get the result:

```
unsigned int result = power<5>(3);
```

I thought it obvious, but just for clarification:  This method requires that you know the exponent at compile-time.

Since [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) exists, it is a bit silly to use a loop, but it can be done:

```
unsigned int base = SOME_BASE;
unsigned int exponent = SOME_EXPONENT;
unsigned int result = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < exponent; result *= base, ++i);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The inputs in the question are determined at run time, not at compile time.

Comment: @dornhege One of the inputs is determined at compile time (the exponent).  The base can be determined at runtime.  And since it is rather silly to compute powers using a loop (when `std::pow` exists), this was just a different approach to the silly question.

Comment: @dornhege: Sure it works ... *biiiig* switch statement ... *ducks-and-runs*.